# Button setText not showing '&'

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I am using `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button` and the `setText` method.

I am doing,

```
myButton.setText("A & B");
```

However, the `&` symbol is not displayed.

I have tried,

```
myButton.setText("A \\& B");
myButton.setText("A '&' B");
myButton.setText("A \& B"); \\not allowed
```

and none of them work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is clearly stated in [`#setText`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FButton.html) doc,

> *Mnemonics are indicated by an **'&'** that causes the next character to be
>   the mnemonic*. When the user presses a key sequence that matches the
>   mnemonic, a selection event occurs. On most platforms, the mnemonic
>   appears underlined but may be emphasized in a platform specific
>   manner. ***The mnemonic indicator character '&' can be escaped by
>   doubling it in the string, causing a single '&' to be displayed.***

So it should be like this,

```
myButton.setText("A && B");
```